A workflow to trigger another on a branch other than the main
I have a build workflow in repo1 that needs to trigger (at the end) a deploy workflow on a no main branch in repo2.
How can I make the build workflow in repo 1 trigger the deploy workflow in no main branch in repo 2?
Repo1 and repo2 are private. The run is in self hosted runner.
I tried with "on: repository-dispatcher" but I have always "message": "Not Found" when the build workflow triggers the deploy workflow. The same code succeed when I change the deploy workflow to the main branch of repo2 (this is not what I need).

You can make use of this step:
- name: Trigger workflow
  shell: bash
  run: |
    curl -L \
    -X POST \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
    https://api.github.com/repos/$YOUR_REPOSITORY_NAME/actions/workflows/$YOUR_WORKFLOW_FILENAME.yaml/dispatches \
          -d '{"ref": "${{ github.ref_name }}","inputs": {"input-1": "some-value","input-2": "${{ inputs.some-value-2 }}"'

In there you can remove/add inputs as necessary, but the important part is -d '{"ref": "${{ github.ref_name }}" in which you can point to any branch you'd like to. In the example I'm using the github context to get the ref name but you can hardcode a value too.

The solution I just found:

In the repo1 (sender): use the curl action mentioned by @bhito
In the repo2 (triggered): the main and no main branch must have the same workflow file name. Delete the content of the main branch workflow. Specify the trigger action on: repository_dispatch in the workflow of no main branch. (With this, the dispatch action find the file in repo2 and as it is empty, it will trigger the workflow of the branch given in the curl action with the param "ref")

Hope this help!
